# How to compute the quadratic variation of a compound poisson process?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, quadratic-variation

The jump diffusion model is defined as 
$$dS_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t dW_t + S_t d \left(\sum^{N_t}_{i=1}(V_i - 1)\right)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$
, where ${V_i}$ is a sequence of iid non-negative random variables and it is independent of $W_t$. In the Merton's jump diffusion model ,
$log(V) \sim N(\mu_J, \sigma^2_J)$ and $ N_t$ is a poisson process with rate $\lambda$.

I was asked to apply Ito lemma to $(d \;logS_t)$ to obtain the following:

$$S_t = S_0 exp \left( \left(\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \right)t + \sigma W_t\right) \prod^{N_t}_{j=1}V_j \;\;\;\;\;\;\;(2)$$

I literally do not know how to solve this problem because of the term $d \left(\sum^{N_t}_{i=1}(V_i - 1)\right)$. This is how far I got to:

$$dlogS_t = \frac{1}{S_t} \left( \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t dW_t + S_t d \left(\sum^{N_t}_{i=1}(V_i - 1)\right)\right) - \frac{1}{2S_t^2} d[S,S]_t$$

What exactly is $d[S,S]_t$ ? I know that 
$$d[S,S]_t = \sigma^2 S^2_t dt + ...$$
But what is that "..." ?

Comment: Well, *apply Itô's lemma to* $d(\log S)$... What did you find for $d\langle S\rangle$, already?

Comment: That's the part I have trouble with.  I have no idea how to solve $d<S>$ ? Applying ito lemma to $d(log S)$ is straightforward.

Comment: Which parts of $dS$ enter into $d\langle S\rangle$? Not many... (As an aside, note that if your trouble is that you cannot compute $d\langle S\rangle$, this is what your question should mention.)

Comment: Sorry. I still cannot figure out the answer. Can you write an answer please ?

Comment: @Did, please see update of my question

Comment: So... $dS=Adt+BdW+SdC$ for some suitable $(A,B)$ and $C_t$ the sum of the $V_i-1$ up to $N_t$. What do you think $d[C]$ is?

Comment: That's the part that I do not know. If it is quadratic variation of a poisson process or compensated poisson process, it is going to be just the poisson process. But we are talking about the quadratic variation of a compound poisson process here, which is why I got stuck.

Comment: If $d[C]$ is out of reach, just go back to the definition. How is $d[C]$ defined exactly and what does the definition yields in this specific case?

Comment: I tried that and my belief is that quadratic variation is sum of squares of jumps and this yield $d[\sum^{N_t}_{i = 1}(V_i -1)] = d(V_i - 1)^2$, but it doesn't seem to lead me to equation 2 above. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Belief? Which belief? I am referring you to the *definition* of [C], what is this definition already?

Comment: I mean from my understanding quadratic variation is the sum of squares of jumps, $[X,X]_t = \sum_i (\Delta X_i) (\Delta X_i)$

Comment: This is not the definition (and *understanding* is as offtopic as *belief* here) but this will do... So, [C] is... hence d[S] is... Come! Wake up!

Comment: Sorry. I really do not understand these concepts. Please elaborate.

Comment: I read this link already. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation  . But I still don't know what I do not understand.

Comment: *Concepts*? Again? There are no concepts here, just definitions to apply. So, what did you find for [C] and for [C,W] when you tried to **compute** them?

Comment: I find that $[C] = \sum_i (\Delta V_i - 1) = 0$, since V_i does not jump and $[C,W] = 0$. I have been stuck for this question for more than a day now. I have put in a lot of time to think through this but I failed.

Comment: No, [C]=0 is absurd. You did not *apply the definition* to compute [C]...

Comment: How about $[C] = \sum_s[\Delta \sum^{N_s}_{i=1}(V_i - 1)]^2 $ ?

Comment: @Did is the above correct ?

Comment: *Not even wrong*, I would say... Personally, I would be in great trouble if I had to compute the RHS of your formula. What does it *mean* exactly?

Comment: @Did, Can you please show me the solution if you know the answer ? Because I have definitely shown that I have put in the effort to try to come up with an answer but failed. I have been stuck in this problem for days now.

Comment: If I'm not totally mistaken, you didn't apply Itô's formula correct. There is one more term missing...

Comment: @saz can you provide an answer and indicate what went wrong  please ? Because I am not sure how to proceed anymore.

Comment: @mynameisJEFF Difficult to help you if you do not apply Ito's formula correctly. Then I don't even know which version of Itô's formula you are using. However, there are two answers now which might answer your questions...

Comment: @saz are you saying that the equation (2) I got is wrong ?

Comment: @mynameisJEFF There are several typos in it. But, actually, I meant the line below where you have calculated $\log S_t$. (Have a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C5%8D's_lemma#Non-continuous_semimartingales - See that there is something missing?)

Comment: Okay. I will look into it later, as I am working on something else now. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that your SDE defining the $S_t$ process is problematic in the term "$S_t\text d\Big(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N_t}(V_i-1)\Big)$". Intuitively, this term should capture instantaneous random jumps when they occur in any given realisation of the process. That is, if a jump occurs at time $t$, then the process jumps from $S_{t-}$ to $S_{t-}V_t$, where $S_{t-}$ is the left limit of the process at time $t$. So, it makes more sense for $S_t$ to be the jump-diffusion Levy process (so *right-continuous, left-limit*) defined by
$$
\text dS_t = \mu S_{t-}\text dt + \sigma S_{t-}\text dW_t + \text d\Big(\sum\limits_{0\leqslant r\leqslant t}S_{r-}(V_r - 1){\bf 1}_{\{N_r-N_{r-}=1\}}\Big),\tag{1}
$$

with jumps determined by a Compound Poisson process independent of $\{W_t\}_{t>0}$. That is, a Poisson process $\{N_t\}_{t>0}$ determines when jumps occur, and the size of such a jump at time $t$ is determined as $S_{t-}(V_t - 1)$ (where $\log V_t\sim\mathcal N(\mu_{J},\sigma^2_{J})\ $ for i.i.d. $V_t$).

Assuming $(1)$ for your SDE and $\mathbb E[\int_{0}^{T}S_{u-}^2\text du] < \infty$, Ito's lemma for jump-diffusion processes is applicable here. Note that, for a $\ C^{1,2}\ $ function $\ f:[0,T]\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, the process $f(t,S_t)$ satisfies

> $$
> \begin{eqnarray*}
> f(t,S_t) - f(0,S_0) &=& \int_{0}^{t}(\partial_uf + \mu S_{u-}\partial_sf + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S_{u-}^2\partial_{ss}f)\text du \\
> && + \sigma \int_{0}^{t}S_{u-}\partial_sf~\text dW_u + \sum_{0\leqslant r\leqslant t}(f(r,S_r)-f(r-,S_{r-})){\bf 1}_{\{N_{r}-N_{r-}=1\}}\,.
> \end{eqnarray*}
> $$

This is simply Ito's lemma for a diffusion process but, in addition, the final term adds the change in the process due to the jumps determined by the compound Poisson process. So, choosing $f(S_t):=\log S_t$ gives us

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\log\Big(\frac{S_t}{S_0}\Big) &=& (\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t + \sigma W_t + \sum_{0\leqslant r\leqslant t}{\bf 1}_{\{N_{r}-N_{r-}=1\}}\log\Big(\frac{S_{r-}V_r}{S_{r-}}\Big) \\
&=&(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t + \sigma W_t + \sum_{0\leqslant r\leqslant t}{\bf 1}_{\{N_{r}-N_{r-}=1\}}\log V_r\,.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Therefore, in your notation,

> $$
> S_t = S_0 e^{(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t + \sigma W_t}\prod_{i=1}^{N_t}V_i\,.
> $$

Comment: I just want to ask in the part where you have $log(\frac{S_{r-} V_r}{S_{r-}})$, shouldn't it be $log(\frac{S_{r-} (V_r- 1)}{S_{r-}})$ ?

Comment: Using $S_r = S_{r-}V_r$ when a jump occurs at time $r$, we have $$f(r,S_r)-f(r-,S_{r-}) = \log(S_r)-\log(S_{r-}) = \log\Big(\frac{S_r}{S_{r-}}\Big) = \log\Big(\frac{S_{r-}V_r}{S_{r-}}\Big)$$

Comment: Yes , I understand that part, as it is based on the ito doeblein formula for jump process. However, I don't understand why is the minus 1 missing ?

Comment: @mynameisJEFF, If you understand that part, then why do you think there should be a "-1"?

Comment: O. -1 is a constant so it doesn't constitute a jump. Am I right ?

Comment: @mynameisJEFF, You have to be clearer in your statements. The size of a jump, when it occurs at time $r$,  is $S_r - S_{r-} = S_{r-}V_r-S_{r-} = S_{r-}(V_r - 1)$. This is where the "-1" comes from. Ito's lemma implies that when the function is $\log S_r$ the size of the jump is what I have stated in my first response to your question: no "-1" there.

Comment: My question was actually : why is there no minus 1 in the jump size? That's what I have been asking. And that's why I said minus 1 is a constant and hence no jump size.

Comment: @mynameisJEFF, The jump size, $\log(S_r)-\log(S_{r-})$, does not have a "-1" because this difference of functions does not simplify to have a "-1". Contrastingly, the jump size, $S_{r}-S_{r-}$ has a "-1" because this expression, when simplified, has it. The difference between the two cases has nothing to do with "-1" being a constant (and not representing a jump); it is purely a consequence of the way the functions/expressions simplify. By simply using the definitions of jump sizes for functions of a stochastic process, you will obtain the correct expressions in each case.

Comment: sorry for confusing you. I understand exactly what you said. The minus one that you were talking about was different from the minus one that I talked about. And you are definitely right about what you said. I just want to verify one thing: when there is a jump diffusion model $dS_t$, the quantity that leads to a jump is $S_t d\left( \sum_{i=1}^{N_t}(V_i-1)\right)$. However, I am not sure what is the jump size ? Is it $S_t V_i$ or $S_t (V_i -1)$ ? I am not talking about the minus one in your answer because I understood that bit already.

Comment: @mynameisJEFF, I see; I appreciate the clarification. Note, the expression $S_t d\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{N_t}(V_i-1)\Big)$ doesn't make sense: it doesn't follow from the definition of a jump for the process $S_t$. As I stated in my answer, It should be $$\text d\Big(\sum\limits_{0\leqslant r\leqslant t}(S_{r}-S_{r-}){\bf 1}_{\{N_r-N_{r-}=1\}}\Big) = \text d\Big(\sum\limits_{0\leqslant r\leqslant t}S_{r-}(V_r - 1){\bf 1}_{\{N_r-N_{r-}=1\}}\Big),$$ because the jump size in this case is $S_r-S_{r-}$, as we have been discussing.

Comment: @kik3 , Thank you for answering my lengthy comments. So the minus one in $S_t d(\sum_{i=1}^{N_t}(V_i - 1))$ is what bothers me. I always wonder why they have it there in the first place.

Comment: @mynameisJEFF, you really shouldn't be bothered about signs in an erroneous mathematical expression. My advice: If the expression is wrong, don't waste your time trying to understand it because, by definition, you shouldn't be able to understand it. :) I certainly don't in this case.

Comment: @kik3, yep you 're right. I am just a pedantic person. And quant finance is not really my area, I should focus on my main area, which is statistics. Thank you very much for answering my question anyway.

Comment: @mynameisJEFF, You are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

In your case

the quadratic variation can be obtained by formally squaring the SDE
$
d[S,S]_t = dS_t \cdot dS_t =\left(  \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t dW_t + S_t d \left(\sum^{N_t}_{i=1}(V_i - 1)\right) \right)^2
$
using the fact that
$
(\mu S_t)^2 dt^2 = 0
$
and 
$
\mu S_t dt \cdot \sigma S_t dW_t =0
$
we get

$
d[S,S]_t = \sigma^2 S_t^2 dt +  2 [ d\left(\sum^{N_t}_{i=1}(V_i - 1)\right), \mu S_t dt ] +
2 [ d\left(\sum^{N_t}_{i=1}(V_i - 1)\right), dW_t ] +   [ d\left(\sum^{N_t}_{i=1}(V_i - 1)\right), d\left(\sum^{N_t}_{i=1}(V_i - 1)\right) ]_t 
$.

Since $V_i $ are i.i.d. $ [dV_i, dt ]=0$ and $ [dV_i, dW_t ]=0$ and  $ [dV_i, dV_j ]=\delta_{i\,j}$.
For the last term we also have $[dV_i  , dV_i ] = dV_i$.
Then finally

$
dlogS_t = \frac{1}{S_t} \left( \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t dW_t + S_t d \left(\sum^{N_t}_{i=1}(V_i - 1)\right)\right) - \frac{1}{2S_t^2}  \sigma^2 S^2_t dt =
$

$
dlogS_t = \left( \mu - \frac{1}{2 }  \sigma^2 \right) dt + \sigma \;  dW_t + d\left(\sum^{N_t}_{i=1}(V_i - 1)\right)
$.

Comment: $[dV_i-1, dV_i-1]=0$ ... why is that?

Comment: A Poisson process has quadratic variation equal to itself. This is because it is a pure jump process with jump sizes equal to 1. If $V_t$ is the Poisson process then the only contribution to the quadratic variation $[V,V]$ comes from the jumps.

Comment: my mistake. I overlooked.

Comment: Is this answer wrong?